# How to make Vlookup ignore blank cells while still checking to see if the ones with a value inside are correct

Tags: database, google-sheets

I am currently making a tardy counter system for my principal as of right now I am having issues with trying to make it so that whenever a new entry is put into the Datasheet it references to the ID sheet and checks to see if it's correct and if it is the cell next to it is blank if it is incorrect it should say error but every time when I try =IF(A2:A="","",ARRAYFORMULA(if(VLOOKUP(A2:A, ID!A1:A,1,FALSE)=A2:A, "", "error")))

it correctly checks but if any are wrong it outputs N/A I'm fine with that on the ones with a value in it but I need to get rid of the "N/A" corresponding to the blank cells

in summary, I need it to count the values that don't match the ID sheet as wrong rather than the blank cells as wrong

I tried multiple if functions but had no good results

also here is a [copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRpji_LESpogMGiAqTnuAHAYxkxQbYOrt8x4PF1LW24jrcmZ6IUdqgX4p_-2eDeAA1s5ly6LeWjxD7s/pub?output=xlsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(A2:A,ID!A:A,1,)=A2:A,),"error")))
```

Comment: thank you so much I was trying to figure this out for days T_T

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `ISBLANK()` function. Ex. `IF(ISBLANK($A2),`...

I got this working in google sheets, try it out:

`=IF(isblank($A2),"", IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, ID!A:A,1,FALSE)=$A2), "", "error"))`

Comment: hello it seems that it isn't infinite also I see that it doesn't provide "error" if one of the values is incorrect